# how to add time information to an evaluated org-mode code block?

Tags: org-mode

I'd like to be able to add additional information of when a block was run to the result:

ie.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC js
var a = 4
var b = 3

return a + b
#+END_SRC
```

```
#+RESULTS:
: 7 @ Thurs 8th Dec 2:00pm EST
```

is there a way to do that?

Comment: I have not heard of this feature but **I would like it**. Perhaps be hacking the `:cache` feature to include 2 strings in the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option `org-babel-hash-show-time` that you can set to `t` but it is used in conjunction with the `:cache` argument as @mankoff speculated in a comment. Try this:

```org
* source block


  #+begin_src emacs-lisp :cache "yes"
    (+ 3 6)
  #+end_src

  #+RESULTS[(2020-12-17 15:34:18) 34e9...]:
  : 9
 
* Code                                                                                                        :noexport:
  #+begin_src emacs-lisp
    (setq org-babel-hash-show-time t)
  #+end_src

  #+RESULTS:
  : t
```

The time stamp will be updated if you change the code block in any way, so that the calculated hash value changes - but if you just hit `C-c C-c` repeatedly, the hash value does not change and the time stamp remains at the value it had when the block was initially evaluated.

Comment: that works great! thanks.