# How can I tangle a specific org mode header from commandline?

Tags: org-mode, command-line-arguments

`$ cat foo.org`

```
* A
#+begin_src text :tangle a.txt
123
#+end_src 
* B
#+begin_src text :tangle b.txt
456
#+end_src
```

Now I change 123 to 1234 and save foo.org

`$ cat foo.org`

```
* A
#+begin_src text :tangle a.txt
1234
#+end_src 
* B
#+begin_src text :tangle b.txt
456
#+end_src
```

Via inotify I can tangle the whole file e.g. `emacs --batch --eval "(require 'org)" --eval '(org-babel-tangle-file "foo.org")'`

But how can I **tangle only header A** (a.txt)?

Comment: I don't think there is a workflow that you can automate easily: the `tangle` header is not particularly flexible. Are you trying to avoid recreating `b.txt` because of the extra work? Or because you don't want e.g. its timestamp to change? If the former, I wouldn't worry too much about it. If the latter, I would add another layer, probably in a Makefile rule: `a-final.txt` depends on `a.txt` with the rule `cmp a-final.txt a.txt || mv a.txt a-final.txt`, i.e. produce `a.txt` but only rename it to `a-final.txt` if it differs from the previously produced file.  The rest of the project ...

Comment: ... only uses `a-final.txt`. Similarly for `b.txt` etc.

Comment: Thank you @NickD Say I change node 150 out of 1000 nodes, it would be rather noisy to tangle all node files instead only the changed one.

Comment: What do you mean "noisy"? If tangling 1000 files takes too long, you can split the file into pieces. Do you really have a thousand code blocks to be tangled in a single file? What is the use case?

Comment: @NickD I think it is easy to automate: The SRC block must be named. Navigate to it, then tangle-this-block (prefix arg to `org-babel-tangle`). Note that this use-case answers the question title, which doesn't seem to be the same as the question example...

Comment: @mankoff - that's a good idea. I had forgotten about the prefix arg case.

Comment: @mankoff This looks like a manual task (..navigate to it..), though I want it scripted from commandline. Hope I understood your comment correctly.

Comment: @412p9wej Not manual. You can jump to a named code block with a function. I don't recall that function name at the moment, but the algorithm I described is scriptable. You could even pass in the named block from the command line.

Comment: Is this an XY problem? https://xyproblem.info/ There is a `:cache` header arg that may do what you want. I just learned you can include the time of the last eval in the result header: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/62322/how-to-add-time-information-to-an-evaluated-org-mode-code-block

Comment: `org-babel-find-named-block` and `org-babel-goto-named-src-block` are probably the functions that @mankoff is referring to.